# Xcode two finger swipe to go back is broken in Xcode 12.5?

Tags: xcode

I am using the two finger swipe gesture to go back on Xcode a lot.
At least I used to because it seems to be broken since a few weeks now. Instead of going one step back, it now appears to jump two steps, making the feature completely unusable for me.

What I have tried:

- restart Xcode
- restart Mac
- go through ~/Library/Developer/Xcode and delete or change various settings (getting desperate)

...but to no avail.

So I am starting to think that this my be an actual software bug in the particular Xcode version (I am using 12.5) but it seems unlikely because an issue like this should be easily caught by the engineer even before submitting the build to QA – just by the developer building the Xcode version, presumably with Xcode itself.

Does anyone else experience this? Is there some broken setting or cache that needs to be reset? Or can the hypothesis be backed up that this is indeed a software bug and all we can do is sit on our hands and try to reprogram years of muscle-memory to use `control-command-left` instead?

Comment: Did you find a solution, same happening for me with xcode 12.5

Comment: No - at this point I believe it's just a (pretty annoying) bug.

Comment: Actually I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/n1c2yc/is_anyone_elses_xcode_file_go_back_swipe/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: It's still broken in Xcode 13.0 beta

Comment: Xcode 12.5~13.0 beta4  too.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround `control-command-left` 

Comment: Seems to be fixed in Xcode 13 beta 5!

Comment: You're right @dchakarov

Comment: Yes, it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode13 release fix it.
"methods

- Additional bug fixes and stability improvements"